# JavaScript - How to save a selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a question about how to save a selected options in a select box.

I created a select box with few options, a "save and show" button, and a reset button.

But I don't know how to save the selected items whenever I'm jumping to the page (unless I select the reset button to change my option) .

Thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: put up some code (preferably on jsfiddle)

Comment: Not preferably on jsfiddle.  Preferably here.  Edit your question and hit Ctrl+M to access the on site editor.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you do so. When asking a question, be [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and be sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Save it in a cookie or localStorage. When the page loads, check if the cookie exists, and then set the value of the `<select>` to that.